# Double CSS Property otherwise the property won't work

Tags: css, properties, double, border

I am building a website with the twitter bootstrap framework.
But the property Border-box works only when I put it two times in my stylesheet.
Like:

```
 *{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;

}
*{
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

Otherwise if I just add it one time, the border will appear outside the div but that will push the div down.
I'm just using the standard Bootstrap.css and a style.css.
What to do?

Example:  http://www.donvos.nl/stack/

Comment: That's strange. Could you make a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: I'm going to guess you don't have the two occurrences exactly adjacent. The rules in between could be overriding the first rule, and the second, by virtue of showing up later, overrides those.

Comment: just make a demo your how exactly you are implementing the properties please show us...... you can use www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting a box sizing property on all elements, surely you don't want that on inline things like `p`? Just target the ones you do want

Comment: I uploaded it on my server.[link](http://www.donvos.nl/stack)

Comment: @Andy box-sizing only applies to elements that accept a width or height, and as far as I know, inline-elements don't. So, it shouldn't cause too many problems. Though, I could be wrong.

Comment: Re: `box-sizing`, it's pretty safe. See [this article from Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to [an error in your style sheet](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.donvos.nl%2Fstack%2Fcss%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en):

```
@import url{'bootstrap.css'};
```

Should be:

```
@import url('bootstrap.css');
```

(parens, not curley braces)

This is making the CSS parser ignore the first block.